# necesito ayuda con codigo php a mysql

Tags: php, mysql

necesito ayuda con un formulario que e hecho y al momento de insertar lo datos de php a mysql no se insertar y no se porque [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

hice eso pero me aparece este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si el dato a enviar es un string debes utilizar comillas para que mysql lo interprete; intenta no usar `ñ` como nombres de campos o variables

Comment: Hola prueba poner VALUES('$nombre', '$email', '$contraseña', '$cedula', '$foto'), tambien puedes hacer un echo $sql para ver el query que estas mandando y verificar que esta bien.

Comment: Seria mucho mejor si en vez de poner la captura de pantalla, copiaras y pegaras el código aquí, seria mucho mas legible para nosotros...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
 $Resultado = $sql->execute([$Nombre, $email, $contra, $cedula, $foto]);

if ($Resultado === true) {
        echo "Registrado con éxito";
}else{
        echo "mal";
}
```

si tienes un id autoincrementable aumenta  un "?"en la primera linea
y un '0' en las variables de la segunda linea